# how to apply scroll bar for div after exceeding its maximum height

Tags: jquery

I have a pop up where I have 4 divs in it and my max height for the main div is 450 px I need to show the scroll bar if my div height exceeds 450px using jquery how can I do this with jquery

```
If('#mydiv'.height > '450px')
jQuery('#mydiv').css("overflow-y", "scroll');
```

But this is not working

Answer (score 0):

.height() returns only the unitless height. And you need to call the height()

```
if($('#mydiv').height() > 450)
  {
     $('#mydiv').css("overflow-y", "scroll");
  }
```

You can also try using CSS:

```
#mydiv {
   max-height: 400px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9op8b63f/

Answer (score 0):

Use `height()` to calculate the height,I prefer not to add `css` in jquery using `css` method,instead add a class that contains the style is a better option,hope this helps ref http://api.jquery.com/height/

```js
if($('.test').height()>450)
{
  $('.test').addClass('scroll')

}
```

```css
.scroll
 {
    overflow-y:auto;
    max-height:450px
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
<p>SomeText</p>
</div>
```